# How to use MySQL LIKE in comma separated values

Tags: mysql, where-clause, sql-like

I have a simple table names `locations` with 3 fields

```
ID      |   location    |   sub_location
------------------------------------------
1       |   loc1        |   sub1,another,sub3
2       |   loc2        |   test1,test
```

How can I get matching values from `location` or `sub_location` based on users input?
In simple, user will enter few letters in a text box. I have to check if any matching value is there in `location` or `sub_location`. But the issue is that I have comma separated values in `sub_location` column. Each comma separated words should be considered as different values and the result should be single values.
Imagine that user entered 'sub' as search term, then my query is something like this. But it will not work, and throws query error near to WHERE clause. Any idea?

```
SELECT ID, location, sub_location FROM locations WHERE location LIKE %sub% OR WHERE sub_location LIKE %sub%
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ID, location, sub_location 
FROM locations 
WHERE location LIKE'%sub%' 
  OR sub_location LIKE '%sub%'
```

Without second *Where* clause just add *OR*

Comment: MySQL error. #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%sub% OR sub_location LIKE %sub% LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1

Comment: I guess you should write `... like '%sub%' ...` with single quotes around the string

Comment: Missing `single quote`.

Comment: Yeap sorry i just copied select from quetion

Comment: Thanks. That solved the main issue. But still any way to get the single matching string instead of entire value, from that comma separated values?

Comment: Separate you mean like this one _sub1,sub2,sub3_? **Like** works fine with it

Comment: @The : I have edited the table in question. If user enter 'sub' as search term, using your solution it will show `sub1,anothersub,sub3` as result. But I want only the matching `sub1` and `sub3`

Comment: You have got answer above.

Comment: @The : I think you have no idea what I am asking now? Lol. Anyway thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

`select * from locations where (location = input) or`
`(sub_location like concat('%',input, ',%') or`
`sub_location like concat('%,',input, ',%') or`
`sub_location like concat('%,',input, '%') or`
`sub_location like concat('%',input, '%') )`